# How to get the clipboard content in adb shell？

Tags: android, adb, emulation, clipboard

I run the command `service call clipboard 1` in adb shell to get the clipboard content, but it returns: `Result: Parcel(fffffffc ffffffff   '........')`, while I make sure it has content in the clipboard.

I don't know how to run the service clipboard successfully. It looks the command run failed.  I try to run the command: `service call clipboard 3`,  and it returns:

```
Result: Parcel(
  0x00000000: 00000000 00000001 00000001 ffffffff '................'
  0x00000010: 00000001 0000000a 00650074 00740078 '........t.e.x.t.'
  0x00000020: 0070002f 0061006c 006e0069 00000000 '/.p.l.a.i.n.....')".
```

The env is linux + android sdk emulator + android 4.4.2, Please advise how to get the clipboard content? Thanks!

Comment: This is no longer possible

Comment: The android 4.x.x does not support this service? so could u give any advice to get the clipboard content? thanks a lot~

Comment: seriously, there's gotta be a way, especially with root